# How to open phpMyAdmin on macOS Mountain Lion (10.7) with XAMPP

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

How do I access phpMyAdmin on my Mac? I heard that use can use `localhost/phpmyadmin` but it returns server not found. I installed PHP, MySQL and Apache with XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the XAMPP control panel, click start for both Apache and MySQL. There should a button labelled “admin” to the right of MySQL and if you click that it should open phpMyAdmin.